# Rendering differences between Mobile App and Web App when using Capacitor

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, ionic-framework

I have recently completed the workflow described on the [Capacitor website](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios) to convert my react app to a mobile web app for iOS.

It's a really impressive tool, but I've noticed some small differences in the way the Mobile and Web apps render (see picture below). You can see the Mobile App in the simulator on the left, the Web App in a browser in the centre, and developer tools on the right.

Does anyone know why such differences arise?  Is there any way to debug this? I can't tell what in the CSS might be causing the layout differences, so am having to revert to trial and error and am not getting anywhere that way.

You can see and grab the code from my sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-hypatia-90ihl?file=/src/App.js).

[image]

Comment: Can you share some more of the CSS? Seems like the issue could be with `shelves-popup-head`.

Comment: Hey @johnborges. Thanks for taking a look at this.  I've included a link to the javascript and css in the question.  Does this give you any further insight into what is going on?